# What is this armor stand for punching in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, mod-identification

I once saw in one of the direwolf20's let's plays the armor stand which you can punch and it displays the amount of damage you make. I couldn't catch the name of the item in WAILA and don't know where to find it in the mod pack. Who can say what is this item on the screenshot?
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This is a Test Dummy from [MmmMmmMmmMmm](http://minecraft.curseforge.com/mc-mods/225738-mmmmmmmmmmmm)<sup>*</sup>. The mod was created by Boni, who is one of the people working on Tinker's Construct, and it's available for Minecraft 1.7.10.

> The dummy can be placed in the world, where it'll stand silently, judging your every action. It'll wiggle funny if you hit it, screaming large numbers of damage at you. It can be dressed up to look even more awesome. This will please the dummy, making the numbers smaller.

<sup>* In case you are confused about the mod name: [click](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t05G0983BcI)</sup>